# How can I preserve entity characters using Xml Document?

Tags: c#, xml, unity-game-engine

My question is simple, but I just can't find why I have this problem and can't resolve it.
I need to read a XML file with values and use them on Unity. For now on, I read my document with its path :

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(path);
XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
```

I have a Namespace Manager already configured.
I read my data like this :

```
string text = node.SelectSingleNode("x:textRuns/x:DOMTextRun/x:characters", nsmgr).InnerText.Replace("&#xD;", Environment.NewLine);
```

My XML and the data I would like to extract :

```
<characters>Third occupant&#xD;folding seat</characters>
```

My objective is to replace this entity character : "& #xD;" with an Environment.NewLine.

I tried to :

- Formalize the Xml in a file with a replace
- Read with an InnerText, and an InnerXml
- Make an entity char "detector"
- Get the node with all its content (OuterXML)

It looks like this char, however you read it, is exclude and not readable, I just can't have it on my console.

Comment: Please add what you have tried so far and highlight exactly where you struggle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entity has already been replaced once you extracted `InnerText`. Problem is, you have a CR (carriage return; 0x0D, `\r`) instead of a LF (line feed; 0x0A, `\n`). So replace `"\r"` by `Environment.NewLine`:

```cs
public static void Main() {
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml("<characters>Third occupant&#xD;folding seat</characters>");
    string text = doc.SelectSingleNode("/characters").InnerText;
    text = text.Replace("\r", Environment.NewLine);
    Console.WriteLine(text);
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! It worked.
Didn't know It worked like that, I can't upvote but help appreciated.

Comment: @AlexisBrouard: no worries, I have enough reputation to not care about it. I'm glad I could help.